# Backbone.js: Access JSON returned inside an HTML fragment served over Ajax?

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js

I'm building a web application that uses Django for the back-end, and Backbone for a user-responsive front-end.

When the user carries out a search (or loads more results for an existing search) I retrieve results via Ajax, using a partial template served by Django.

This works fine, but I'd also like to update the search filters so that the user cannot refine for querysets with zero results.

For example: if the user searches for cars between $1000-$3000, and no blue cars are available, I want to grey out the "blue" colour selector in the search form. So as well as returning the results, I also return an JSON object with the available colours.

My question is this: I know how to inject the results into an HTML element of the page, and I know how to return JSON in the template fragment. **But how can I access that JSON from inside Backbone?**

This is my Backbone model. It listens for search events, when it performs an Ajax request, and sets its 'results' property to the template fragment returned by Ajax:

```
var SearchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({  ..
  performSearch: function() {
  $.get(this.get("querystr"), function(html) {
    self.set("results", html);
    // TODO: How to extract JSON results
  });
  } ...
 });
```

The template fragment returned by Django over Ajax contains both HTML and JSON:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var queryset_propeties = JSON.parse('{{queryset_properties|jsonify|escapejs}}');
</script>
<ul id="results">
{% for results in results %}
<li>{{ result }}</li>
{% endfor %}    
</ul>
```

I also have some Backbone code that listens for changes to the results property of the search model, and updates the front-end:

```
var SearchResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({ ...
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on("change:results", this.displayResults, this);
    this.render();
  } ...
  displayResults: function(model, results) {
   this.$el.html(self.model.get('results'));
   // TODO: Use queryset_properties object to update search filters?
   console.log('queryset_properties', queryset_properties);
  } ...
});
```

My problem is that the `queryset_properties` object is not up to date, and I don't know how to access it from inside the Backbone code.

I have thought of the following:

1. Make two `$.get` calls, one to an HTML file and one to a JSON file. I'd like to avoid this because of the extra HTTP overhead.
2. Only return JSON via Ajax, and use this to update all the HTML in Backbone, rather than returning the template from Django. I want to avoid this though, because by returning HTML, the Django application works for non-JS users (like search bots), which is important.
3. Somehow extract the JSON object from the returned HTML, and set it as a Backbone model attribute that I can then use in the usual way - but how to do this, short of using a regex or something equally messy?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is this: I know how to inject the results into an HTML
>   element of the page, and I know how to return JSON in the template
>   fragment. But how can I access that JSON from inside Backbone?

Instead of having those `$.get` requests, use Backbone [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch). It has the appropriate success, and error callbacks just like jQuery's `$.get`.

In order to do it the Backbone way, first you have to set up your [model's URL](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url):

```
var SearchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: this.get("querystr")
});
```

after initializing your model call `fetch`:

```
var sm = new SearchModel({querystr: "http://example.com?car"});
sm.fetch({ // calls model's url
    success: function (model) {
        // you can access the returned json object here by doing:
        model.get('price'); // assuming your json looks like { price: 500 }
    },
    error: function (model) {
    }
 });
```

[Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/)

[Short tutorials](http://backbonetutorials.com/)

Comment: Thanks. `fetch` sounds good, but I'm not sure this is gonna work for me, given that I need to return *both* HTML and JSON in the same request. Or maybe I could return a JSON object, with an HTML string as one of the values...?